# Merging objects into one while retaining positional animation data as a vertex animation

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, export

I am looking to create a vertex animation suitable for use in the source engine. My animation is composed of an 8x8 grid of squares breaking apart in the center.

The problem arises when I attempt to export it: Source assumes that the origins of each object should always be at 0,0,0, so all the squares are moved to the center. I want to merge all of the squares so that their origins are always at 0,0,0 instead of at their centers but so that they still animate correctly.

**[link to blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bstnqsaxycdjrmw/fallingtiles.blend/file)**

*image of scenario*
[image: image of an 8x8 arrangement of squares]

Is it possible to do this in blender? Is there a workaround if not? Are there alternative methods?

Here is a gif of the intended result

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what you mean when you say "breaking apart in the center"?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Here is a gif of the intended result ([link](https://i.imgur.com/0AUWNSW.gifv))

Comment: Your goal is to set all origins to (0,0,0)? If so, you can use the 3d cursor... Make sure the cursor is set to (0,0,0), select all objects, go to *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3d Cursor*...

Comment: @brockmann that is the problem. Changing the origins messes up the positions of the objects when they rotate. They must have their origins at 0,0,0 but they must rotate as if their origins were at their centers.

Comment: @Jadon could you please post blend file of animation?  To clarify (ignoring rotation and scaling) if a square (origin at geometry like pics above)  at starting point  global location (3, 3, 0) drops by 1 to (3, 3, -1)  want to convert that by shifting origin  to global  (0, 0, 0) and moving it to  (0, 0, -1)  and the object animation will work when exported?

Comment: @batFINGER I added a link to the blend file in the post